# AngularJS cascade checkbox selections to select dropdown

Tags: angularjs

Been trying to get this working for a day and finally wanted to post here and see if anyone already solved this. I have group of checkboxes and I want to change the  dropdown to be populated by whatever is CHECKED in checkbox.

So if user picks English and Spanish, I want the  dropdown to only show those 2 options.

Anyway to do it on the page? I think it must be a filter but not sure what it needs to be. Thanks!

```
$scope.languages = [
        {value: "en", name: "English"},
        {value: "es", name: "Spanish"},
        {value: "zh", name: "Chinese"},
        {value: "fr", name: "French"},
        {value: "de", name: "German"},
        {value: "jp", name: "Japanese"}
    ];

    $scope.settings.custom.languages = [{Spanish: 1, English: 1, French: false, Chinese: false, Japanese: false}];

    <label ng-repeat="language in languages" style="width:100px">
    <input type="checkbox" ng-true-value="1" ng model="settings.custom.languages[language.name]" />{{language.name}}
    </label>

    <select  
    class="form-control" 
    ng-model="settings.custom.primaryLanguage"
    ng-options="language.name for language in languages track by language.value">
    </select>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
I decided to just do this:

$scope.settings.custom.languages = [
    {value: "en", name: "English"},
    {value: "es", name: "Spanish"},
    {value: "zh", name: "Chinese"},
    {value: "fr", name: "French"},
    {value: "de", name: "German"},
    {value: "jp", name: "Japanese"}
];

<label ng-repeat="(languageKey, language) in settings.custom.languages">
<input type="checkbox" ng-true-value="1" ng-model="language['enabled']" /> {{language.name}}
</label>

<select  
class="form-control" 
ng-model="settings.custom.defaultLanguage"
ng-options="language.name for language in settings.custom.languages | filter:{enabled:'1'} track by language.value">
</select>
```